# use pagination in flask to order in alphabet

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

i have a list of country i want to use pagination to have all country for etc start with 'A' in a same page and in pagination dont have all of the alphabet right now i can do it with a pure python function to loop into all alphabet and make dictionary with the alphabet as a KEY and countrys as value but i have a problem my pagination have all word in alphabet and i want to see them like :
a, b,.....w, x, y, z and i think its not cool to write a long code for this i watch too many youtube videos and read a lot of dcouments but i cant find my answer i think there is easyest way than this to do it and not a pro so thank you if you dont give me a minus point for post this

i try this but it wont help :

```
country_list = db.session.query(Country).order_by(Country.country_name)
```

i use flask_sqlalchemy with a mysql databse and this is my table for this countrys :

```
class Country(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "country"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    country_name = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False, unique=True)
    about = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)
    iso2 = db.Column(db.String(100))
    phone_cod = db.Column(db.String(100))
    capital = db.Column(db.String(100))
    currency = db.Column(db.String(100))
    city = relationship("City", backref="city")

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Country name : {self.country_name}, country id : {self.id}>"
```

Comment: Why didn't `order_by(Country.country_name)` help?

Comment: @snakecharmerb i want to ech time extract country for etc start wuth A or B

Comment: Flask-SQLAlchemy's pagination function partitions results by quantity (page size) rather than a quality like initial letter. If you want to paginate" by initial letter you need a query such as `Country.query.filter(Country.country_name.like('A%')).all()` in the route, but pass the initial letter from the front end each time. Or, as there are fewer than 200 countries, fetch them all at once and manage display in the front end.

Comment: @snakecharmerb the secound way its sounds good thank you so much i will do it